# debugging 64 bit C++ application on 32 bit gdb tool

Tags: c++, solaris-10

we are using Sun Solaris for our application development and compiling 64 bit application by using -m64.

But the 32 bit GDB tool has been installed in my machine and we are unable to debug our 64 bit application.

The output as

```
$ gdb cxlog
GNU gdb 6.8
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "sparc-sun-solaris2.10"...
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100001464: file cxlogger.c, line 147.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr33/SIR07140/GTB_HOME/GoTx_HOME/samples/cxlog
procfs:4337 -- process not stopped.
procfs: ...giving up...
(gdb) n
procfs: couldn't find pid 12372 (kernel thread 1) in procinfo list.
(gdb).
```

normal debugging commends like next & step are not working.

If I compile my application by using -m32 GDB is working file.

Thanks in Advance.
Sundar Rajendran.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have three choices - in order of my preference:

1. Install 64-bit GDB on the machine.
2. Rebuild your app in 32-bit mode and debug that way.
3. Build your own version of gdb, for 64-bit targets, from sources.

The only way you'll debug a 64-bit binary is to have a gdb that is built for 64-bit [or some other debugger, but whichever it is, it needs to be built for 64-bit targets]